# Webhook execution failed: execution expired

Tags: jenkins, gitlab-ci

I am trying to trigger jenkins build whenever there is a push to GitLab.
I am referring to https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin.

When I test the connection for webhook it shows `execution expired`.

I am using:

- Jenkins ver. 2.60.1
- GitLab version 9.4.0-rc2-ee
- Git lab  plugin 1.4.6

Comment: Did you complete all the required configuration forms both in Jenkins as in GitLab?

Answer (score 1):

The exact [error message](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/20266), clicking "`Test setting`" from GitLab:

```
We tried to send a request to the provided URL but an error occurred: execution expired
```

As mentioned in [issue 128](https://github.com/olipo186/Git-Auto-Deploy/issues/128#issuecomment-242866347):

> This looks and sounds like a configuration or network error.
>   Maybe your machine is not publicly available on the webhook address (firewall etc).

For instance, on Digital Ocean server, you would need to open up the port (mentioned in `git-auto-deploy.conf.json`) in the firewall:

```
sudo ufw allow 8866/tcp
```

Double-check though what you put in `Manage Jenkins > Configure` in term of Gitlab information (connection name, host url, credentials), as mentioned in [jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin issue 391](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/391#issuecomment-247408545).
See [GitLab Integration Jenkins: Configure the Jenkins server](https://gitlab.com/help/integration/jenkins.md#configure-the-jenkins-server)

Answer (score 0):

It means issues in between jenkins server and gitlab or github server.

Like what I did:

I have set my local-IP:port/project/jenkins_project_name

http://192.168.1.21:8080/project/jenkins_project_name

and set the above URL in the gitlab webhook, it shouldn't work - right?

Because it's an IP that's private and not routable.

SO later I realized and set the public-IP and then hook worked.

http://public_IP:8080/project/jenkins_project_name

Note: To routable public-IP, you should expose port in your router [e.g. 8080 was for me or anything want ]

Hope this works.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.
In my case Jenkins is running in an AWS EC2 instance. I have resolved the issue by whitelisting the Public IP addresses of Gitlab on port 443 into the instance security group.